# How to select unique values of column A in each group B and get sum of values in column C for these unique values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have posts dataframe and authors dataframe

I need to calculate favCount of the authors of posts in each day

```
    posts_columns = ["postId", "authorId", "date"]
    posts = [("1", "1", "2020-10-10"),
             ("2", "2", "2020-10-10"),
             ("3", "2", "2020-10-10"),
             ("4", "2", "2020-10-11")
             ("5", "3", "2020-10-11")
             ("6", "3", "2020-10-11")]

    authors_columns = ["authorId", "favCount"]
    authors = [
        ("1", "5"),
        ("2", "3"),
        ("3", "12")]
```

After (inner) joining Posts and Authors dataframes on (posts.authorId=author.authorId) and I got this

```
+----------+--------+---------------+                                  
|      date|authorId|       favCount|
+----------+--------+---------------+
|2020-10-10|       1|              5|
|2020-10-10|       2|              3|
|2020-10-10|       2|              3|
|2020-10-11|       2|              3|
|2020-10-11|       3|             12|
|2020-10-11|       3|             12|
+----------+--------+---------------+
```

Now I want to calculate sum of favCount of authors in each day, the final result should be like this

```
+----------+-------------+                                  
|      date|sum(favCount)|
+----------+-------------+
|2020-10-10|            8|
|2020-10-11|           15|
+----------+-------------+
```

On OCT, 10th I have two authors (1 and 2) with total of 8 favCount (5+3)

On OCT, 11th I have two authors (2 and 3) with total of 15 favCount (3+12)

P.S: I don't want to count favCount for duplicated authors, favCount for each author should be counted once only in each day

P.S(2): I'm using PySpark and Dataframes but I don't mind answers in Pandas or even SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering `df1` as Posts and `df2` as Authors dataframes

```py
result = df1.merge(df2, how= 'inner').drop_duplicates(subset=['date','authorId'])
final = result.groupby([result.date])['favCount'].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , You've saved my day

Comment: I am glad that it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try spark, you can try this

scala code:

```scala
df1.join(df2, Seq("authorId"), "inner").groupBy("date", "authorId").sum()
```

or python:

```py
df1.join(df2, ["authorId"], "inner").groupBy("date", "authorId").sum()
```